# How do I use a DialogFragment if my app doesn't use Fragments?

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

I'm updating an older app that still supports Android 2.0.
There is a new chunk of code that I would really like to put up a custom dialog - but all the docs talk about using DialogFragments.
I'm not using Fragments anywhere in my app, so how do I get a FragmentManager to let me show the dialog?

Or can someone point me to the docs for the pre-Fragment dialog support?

Comment: SupportFragment should do it

Comment: why are you still supporting 2.0, even google does not support 2.0 anymore

Comment: Because 1/3 of our customers are still using devices < 3.0.

Comment: @CasaDelGato I understand but that does not mean you have to support a SDK that according to google's latest distribution report is < 1%. Not to mention 2.0 was only released on the original droid so if anything 2.1 you should target. targeting 2.2 and above lets you use the support library to use fragments and all the google play services that is basically the future of android. http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: @tyczj So, you are saying that I could use a Fragment-Based dialog in a NON-Fragment app, if I upped my min level to Android 2.2?

Comment: that is correct, then you can use the support library to use fragments. read my last comment on my answer

Answer (score 0):

you still create dialogs the same way just without using a fragment.

for example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
```

I would highly recommend you stop supporting 2.0 and start supporting 2.2 and your minimum sdk target so you can switch to using fragments as this is the preferred way to do things now

Comment: Except I need a full custom layout, not just a few buttons.

Comment: so create one then, read the `Dialog` docs. it was only an example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Comment: @CasaDelGato you can create a dialog without fragments _and_ with a full custom layout.  Create your dialog layout in XML and use `setView` method of the builder.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't find the Dialog docs since I made the mistake of using the API docs - which are Fragment only, and kept referring me to DialogFragment.

Comment: Also, I thought Fragments didn't come in until API level 11, isn't that 3.0?

Comment: @CasaDelGato it was first introduced in 3.0 but they have since created a support library where you can use fragments all the way back to 2.2 which is why I said you should stop targeting 2.0 and set your minimum sdk as 2.2. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Android Support Library v4 and also convert all the activities where you need to display the dialog from Activity to FragmentActivity. In this way you don't have to modify your activities but you can use the DialogFragment.